# how to use substring function sqlite android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

suppose I have a table name : **TEST**, that it has 2 columns **ID** and **CONTENT**, like this :

**TEST** TABLE :

**ID** ======= **CONTENT**

0   ======= hello world

now, how can I split **CONTENT** column from 0 index to 5 index to retrieve just **hello** word? (at here, **ID**=> 0)
(I just want to use sql, not other functions in others languages );

Comment: this query returns hello world, I would like to give just hello !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select substr(content, 0, 5) from test
```

Answer (score 1):

> The `substr(X,Y,Z)` function returns a substring of input string X that
>   begins with the Y-th character and which is Z characters long. If Z is
>   omitted then `substr(X,Y)` returns all characters.

The answer to your question is:

```
select substr(content, 0, 5) from test where id >= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `substr()` function in [sqlite3 core functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html). It will let achieve what you need.

Use it as:

```
SELECT substr(content, 0, 5) FROM test WHERE id >= 0;
```

Comment: or `id = 0` if this what you meant in your question by '=>'