# Is it possible to enable/ disable transformation on selected Room Database Dao column?

Tags: android, android-room

Currently, we have the following database table

```
@Entity(
        tableName = "note"
)
public class Note {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "body")
    private String body;

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

The length of the body string, can be from 0 to a very large number.

In certain circumstance, we need to

1. Load the **all** notes into memory.
2. A `LiveData` which is able to inform observers, if there's any changes made in the SQLite `note` table.
3. We just need the first 256 characters of `body`. We do not need entire `body`. Loading entire `body` string for **all** notes might cause `OutOfMemoryException`.

We have the following Room Database Dao

```
@Dao
public abstract class NoteDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM note")
    public abstract LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes();
}
```

`getAllNotes` able to fulfill requirements (1) and (2), **but not (3).**

---

The following `getAllNotesWithShortBody` is a failed solution.

```
@Dao
public abstract class NoteDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM note")
    public abstract LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note")
    public abstract List<Note> getAllNotesSync();

    public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotesWithShortBody() {
        MutableLiveData<List<Note>> notesLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

        //
        // Problem 1: Still can cause OutOfMemoryException by loading 
        // List of notes with complete body string.
        //
        List<Note> notes = getAllNotesSync();

        for (Note note : notes) {
            String body = note.getBody();

            // Extract first 256 characters from body string.
            body = body.substring(0, Math.min(body.length(), 256));

            note.setBody(body);
        }

        notesLiveData.postValue(notes);

        //
        // Problem 2: The returned LiveData unable to inform observers, 
        // if there's any changes made in the SQLite `note` table.
        //
        return notesLiveData;
    }
}
```

---

I was wondering, is there any way to tell Room database Dao: *Before returning List of Notes as `LiveData`, please perform transformation on every Note's body column, by trimming the string to maximum 256 characters?*

---

### Examining the source code generated by Room Dao

If we look at the source code generated by Room Dao

```
@Override
public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
  final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM note";
  final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
  ...
  ...
              final String _tmpBody;
              _tmpBody = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfBody);
              _tmpPlainNote.setBody(_tmpBody);
```

It will be great, if there is a way to supply transformation function during runtime, so that we can have

```
              final String _tmpBody;
              _tmpBody = transform_function(_cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfBody));
              _tmpPlainNote.setBody(_tmpBody);
```

---

p/s Please do not counter recommend Paging library at this moment, as some of our features require entire List of Notes (with trimmed body String) in memory.

---

Comment: Sqlite does have a `substr` function . I think you can try it [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531689/how-to-use-substring-function-sqlite-android) .. I am not sure how does it handles the overflow length .

Comment: The tricky part is, how do you use `substr` in Room Dao and return it as LiveData ?

Comment: @Query("SELECT substr(body,1,256) FROM note")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SUBSTR, one of [SQLite's built-in functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

You need a primary key in your @Entity. Assuming that you call it `id`, you can write a SQL like below.

```
@Query("SELECT id, SUBSTR(body, 0, 257) AS body FROM note")
public abstract LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes();
```

This will return the `body` trimmed to 256 chars.

With that being said, you should consider segmenting your rows. If you have too many rows, they will eventually use up your memory at some point. Using Paging is one way to do it. You can also use LIMIT and OFFSET to manually go through segments of rows.

Comment: Argh... I'm not aware I can specific individual column, for Room to construct a complete Object. Gonna to try that out. We avoid paging at this moment, as we found it is quite difficult to achieve the following without holding entire List in memory: Insert a new note is correct custom sort order, then quickly scroll the recyclerview to the newly inserted note location. We want these UI to happen, even before SQLite finish perform writing - For a fast and smooth user experience.